# Creating a function in r with a boolean option: How do i return the dataframe if no boolean option is presented when calling the function?

Tags: r

I got the following code for a function:

```
data_function <- function(df,condtion_a,condition_b, condition_c= TRUE) {
  df <- df %>%
    filter(col_a == condtion_a & col_b == condition_b) 
    if(condition_c == TRUE) {
      df %>% filter(col_c== TRUE)
    } else if(condition_c== FALSE) { 
      df %>% filter(col_c == FALSE)
    }
    else {
  return(df)
    }
}
```

The code works when I give either `TRUE` or `FALSE` to the condition_c. However, I want an option to just return the `df <- df %>% filter(col_a == condtion_a & col_b == condition_b)`  portion of the code when neither condition_c is `TRUE` or `FALSE`. For example, I want to use this function to work on three ways:

`data_function(df,condtion_a,condition_b, condition_c= TRUE)`

`data_function(df,condtion_a,condition_b, condition_c= FALSE)`

`data_function(df,condtion_a,condition_b)`

with the latter just returning just the  `df <- df %>% filter(col_a == condtion_a & col_b == condition_b)` part when `condition_c` is not present when calling the function. I feel this is a very simple thing but cannot think of how to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the function, the `return(df)` is returning the dataset before the `if/else` condition was applied because the output from that is not updated to 'df'

```
data_function <- function(df,condtion_a,condition_b, condition_c) {
 # subset the rows of the dataset and update it to same object
  df <- df %>%
         filter(col_a == condtion_a & col_b == condition_b) 
 df1 <- if(missing(condition_c)) {
        df
    } else {
 # apply the `if/else if/else` and assign it to a new object or same object
      if(condition_c) {
         df %>%
             filter(col_c)
       } else if(!condition_c) { 
          df %>% 
             filter(!col_c)
     }else {
            df
           }
      }
   
    return(df1)
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not achieve the result I want. It works correctly when `condition_c = TRUE` or `condition_c = FALSE` but when I leave out `condition_c`, for example `data_function(df,condtion_a,condition_b)` it returns the wrong one. It should return df with the filtered with the conditions on `filter(col_a == condtion_a & col_b == condition_b) `. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @BoniPhila Please update with a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: @BoniPhila without a reproducible example, it is difficult to test.  I updated though

Comment: Essentially I have a master dataframe with thousands of rows. This dataframe will go through the function. In order for the function to be succesful, `col_a` and `col_b` need to be filtered out. So  in the end I want to keep those results (what I hoped my original return would do). That would give me successful result A (which is a filtered out data frame). In this df, `condition_c` is not involved, hence why I want the function to not include it. Continued below...

Comment: @BoniPhila I understsand the problem.  But, to test the function, i would suggest to create a small example dataset

Comment: Got it, I'll create one in a sec

Comment: I must apologize, you answer was correct in the first place. I missed the "missing" and of course it wouldn't allow me to get the correct results.Thank you for your help!